# One of these chats doesn't belong!

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

[image: Chat Sidebar Screenshot]

Comment: Which one? I don't understand -- Both these rooms have RPG set as the parent site, both are not deleted or frozen.

Comment: @balpha: I assume @Iszi made the _Running..._ while chatting over at serverfault or similar other site on the network. How does the parent site get set for a room? Is there a reason RPG would be set as the parent site?

Comment: @yhw42: Yeah, I guess. It's the title of a [question on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/239883/running-control-panel-applet-elevated-from-an-elevated-command-prompt); I changed the room parent site accordingly. The room parent site is always set to the creating user's parent site.

Comment: ♫ One of these chats is not like the others / One of these chats doesn't belong / Can you tell which chat is not like the others / Before I finish my song? ♪

Comment: @LeguRi When I first read your comment I thought GraceNote was stalking out meta again.

Comment: @C. Ross - Is that because the little ♪ looks like a [grace note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_note) or does the prominent meta.stackoverflow-user [GraceNote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) have a history of particularly musical/poetic comments? (I'm suddenly tempted to try and organize a "comments in haiku form" day)

Comment: @LeguRi [GraceNote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) often uses those symbols to end her comments.

Comment: @LeguRi I like humming whenever I busy myself with something. ♪ I actually don't burst out into verse that often, [except for that one time...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/80245/revisions)

Comment: @GraceNote - Hahahahaha. I just re-watched Fiddler on the Roof a couple of days ago. GOLD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [create room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) page, it is now really obvious what site you are creating a room for, and you can tweak it to suit. Better?

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't mean for you to go to all that trouble though, which is why I changed it to support.

Answer (score 1):

That room was created by me, with the intent of discussing the topic question from SU or SF (I forget which).  I thought I'd created it from SU/SF, but somehow it ended up here.  I have no clue how or why, or how to adjust it in the future.  If anyone has a killswitch for those things, feel free to throw it - the person I was hoping to chat with obviously isn't responding.

Comment: See [Marc's post](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/913/one-of-these-chats-doesnt-belong/914#914).  You can now select the site you want it attached to.